# How to create real APN Server and how to test the app with APN Server iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

As am an iOS developer. I know to implement the APN in programmatically in our project. But, am assumption is we are receiving the APN message from APN server. I don't know `how we are hosting the the APN message?` `How to create real APN Server for us`? I have searched lot from Google,

http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/
http://www.anima-entertainment.de/iphone-programming-how-to-make-an-apple-push-notification-service-using-php
http://samvermette.com/145

These are i have visited to know to create APN Server. But, i can't understand to create actual server for APN. Can anyone `please help me to create actual APN Server and host message in our server`. And also `how we can test the APN from real APN server`? Is it Possible? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the Apple documentation? You don't seem to have that on your list of what you have looked at. What's wrong with what Apple provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple provides a production and test server (sandbox) that do the communication with the phones.  Your job is to get your app user's device ids (with their permission), and then contact apple to send them messages.  That job is called the "provider", [and you can either build it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1), or now - thanks to a couple new startups - rent it.

I haven't tried any of the services, but if you're finding the do-it-yourself approach too complex, and just want to see some messages get to your test app, it seems a reasonable thing to look at.  I think most have a free tier to try it out.  [Here's the first link](https://www.parse.com/) I found using google.